# How works the Laravel 4 native session driver?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I use all the time the session back-ends drivers provided by the amazing Laravel4 framework.
The Official Doc says:

> By default, Laravel is configured to use the native session driver, which will work well for the majority of applications.

And in fact i keep the default driver and it works fantastically with all my Session things. So, I release my app without any trouble.
I need to understand the "magic" thing about the native driver to compare with all the other options available.

So my question is:
How exactly works the Laravel 4 native session driver ??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: like native php session: stores session id in browser cookie, which it uses to access the session data in server side temporary session file in filesystem. When PHP session is active then it blocks other trying to access same session unitil this one is finished (no async  ajax possible with session data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real benefit of using the native driver is it does not require any additional setup.  If you have PHP setup on the server, and you grant the `/app/storage/sessions` folder the right permissions it will just work.

You don't need to have a database properly configured or install something more advanced like redis (though both of those drivers are available out of the box).

Also please note, it is not using cookies to store your session data (however that too is an option by changing your driver to `cookie`.  It does use a cookie to track your session id though -- as all of the session drivers do.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is closed long time ago, this post seems to have high ranking with 'laravel session' keywords.

Let me remind others of one thing:

- Laravel **4.0** uses '**native**' driver - sessions will be handled by internal PHP session facilities.
- Laravel **4.1** & **4.2** uses '**file**' driver - sessions will be stored in app/storage/sessions. No longer support 'native' driver.(You cannot choose it.)

So if you want to utilize on PHP native session, let's say 'session.upload_progress' feature, you just session_start() and then use the original $_SESSION.

check out the official documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/session

http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/session

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session

Comment: By the way, 'session.upload_progress' is hard to configure. If you have any issues with it, it should be native PHP issue rather than Laravel issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the name says :) **native session driver** is using native php mechanism for session storage (cookies) - laravel is using `laravel/vendor/symfony/http-foundation\Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php` for that.